# Unity webGL - build project on MacOS failed

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

When I try to build unity for webGL I get an error,

> Exception:
>   /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not
>   run properly!

I am using lastest Unity on Mac, so I guess it cannot run il2cpp.exe file, is there any way to use the Xcode compiler instead? or any other solution?

Comment: This is a general error message, which doesn't indicate the cause of the problem. Can you provide more details about the error message (there should be more information in the log)? The il2cpp.exe utility is a _managed_ executable though. It runs via Mono, so it is correct to run it on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my python version, it was 2.6, this process required python 2.7.